# Use annotations on Pytnon 3.6.5

Tags: python, django, chain-of-responsibility

I'm working on a project where I was asked to code some validations using Chain of Responsibility.
I am currently using python 3.9.2 on my machine, but the project on docker is on 3.6.5

This piece of code works nice on my machine, but it breaks on Docker:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Optional


class Handler(ABC):
    """
    The Handler interface declares a method for building the chain of handlers.
    It also declares a method for executing a request.
    """

    @abstractmethod
    def set_next(self, handler: Handler) -> Handler:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def handle(self, request) -> Optional[str]:
        pass
```

The error that shows is the following:

```
 from __future__ import annotations
django_1    |     ^
django_1    | SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Is there a way to make the code work on python 3.6.5?

Comment: [`__annotations__` was introduced in Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/): "This change is going to be introduced gradually, starting with a new __future__ import in Python 3.7". Also see https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html

Comment: *"I am currently using python 3.9.2 on my machine, but the project on docker is on 3.6.5"* - why not make these consistent? Otherwise you're going to hit no end of issues.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the code from refactoring.guru is the fragment I posted, is not my own, I'm asking for a way to do that thing on 3.6.5

Comment: You can read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/ to see what that import would add, and therefore how to work around it (*"when a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition needs to be expressed as a string literal"*). But you'll likely hit other issues, the point of using Docker is for a more consistent environment not less!

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE:*

**TLDR**: `Python 3.6+` reached end of cicle, update to `Python >=3.7`

As pointed out by @ForceBru `annotations` as part of `__future__` was introduced with Python `3.7+`, so you'll need to add de dependency manually (or move up the `python` version, which I would recommend)

A ([deprecated](https://github.com/asottile-archive/future-annotations)) package called `future-annotations` may be a solution to allow old systems to keep working. Following [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/future-annotations/) instructions:

> `pip install future-annotations`

Comment: Your instructions to "add the dependency" only applies to that specific project you're using